# How can I outsource the Vuetify 3 config form the main.js in Vue 3 with Vuetify 3.0.0-beta.4?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3, beta

I use Vue 3 togehter with Vuetify 3.0.0.-beta.4 and my src/main.js file looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

// --- VUETIFY - START ---
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myCustomTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomTheme: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
            background: '#FFFFFF',
            surface: '#FFFFFF',
            primary: '#6200EE',
            'primary-darken-1': '#3700B3',
            secondary: '#03DAC6',
            'secondary-darken-1': '#018786',
            error: '#B00020',
            info: '#2196F3',
            success: '#4CAF50',
            warning: '#FB8C00'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
// --- VUETIFY - END ---

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

The code works perfectly fine but as you can see this becomes very quickly confusing. I would like to outsource the Vuetify part form the src/main,js file into a separate file (src/plugins/vuetify.js) but all my efforts didn't work.

How can I outsource the vuetify part into a separate js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the export functionality:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

And then, in your `main.js` file, import your vuetify configured object and pass it to vue.

Comment: Oh man sometimes the solution can be so simple. Thank you!